# How to reload a webpage without the user noticing?

Tags: greasemonkey

There is a video streaming webpage that stops playing after X minutes.

To resolve this, we have to reload the webpage with "F5" button.

But: is there any very short, ex.: greasmonkey script that can reload the page in ex.: every 5 minutes, without the user noticing?

The purpose is to send a "hello" to the server that we are still alive, so thinking of to open a tab in background then close the opened tab, without the user really noticing, but don't touch the page that has the focus, that is currently playing the video.

Comment: You can analyze the page code and see where it measures the time. Depending on the method, there could be various solutions like clearing of all timers or rewriting the page html/scripts during its first load.

Comment: the "X minutes" limit is on server side, the stream server just stops sending the video data :) we cannot do anything about it... I just had seen applications for Kodi that uses the trick to reload page in every 5 mins...see maxTicking in https://github.com/szabbenjamin/digionline/blob/master/engine/digionline.js

Comment: are you looking for something like Ajax ?